# How do I properly implement a once in a time frame click activated action button using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm still learning RxJS. For a project of mine I wanted to implement this "save only once" functionality.

The code snippet from a video about RxJs is the following:

```
const clickToSave$ = saveClick$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => http.post(saveURL, data) )
)
```

I have the following rewritten code in which I tried to implement a code snippet into my existing codebase.

```
 const saveClick$ = new Observable();
    // TODO: error handling
    const clickToSave$ = saveClick$.pipe( exhaustMap(() => this.http.post(this.xmlendpointPdf, jsonType, this.httpOptions) )
      ).subscribe(
        result => {
          const docUrl = 'test';
          console.log(docUrl);        },
        error => {
          if (error['status'] === 0) {
            this.openAlertDialog('Unknown error');
          } else {
          this.openAlertDialog('The following error has appeared:' + error['statusText']);
          }
          console.log('There was an error: ', error);
        });
      }
```

...but it apparently doesn't work. How am I supposed to bind to a `(click)= ....` event in button's HTML like that?
To recap, what I want is that you can theoretically click on the button as much as you want but it will do the action (which is `http.post` call in this case) only once for a time period so when the user spams the button with clicks. How can I successfully implement this code snippet for my own specific use case (which I imagine a lot of people in the future will look for too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to ask questions if you need more explanation!

**Template**

```
<button (click)="bntClicked($event)">Save Button</button>
<br />
<button #btn>Save Button 2</button>
```

**Code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  //Solution 1 - Not a big fan of this one personally but it does work
  //Manually make sure a subscription finishes before allowing a new one
  activeSubscription: Subscription;
  bntClicked($event) {
    if (!this.activeSubscription) {
      this.activeSubscription = this.saveMock().subscribe({
        next: result => {
          console.log(result);
          this.resetSubscription();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  resetSubscription() {
    this.activeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.activeSubscription = undefined;
  }
  //End solution 1;

  //Solution 2 - I prefer this one

  //We get a reference to the button using ViewChild
  @ViewChild("btn", { static: true }) button: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Option 1
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, "click")
      .pipe(
        //Cancel previous observable and subscribe to new/last one
        switchMap($event => this.saveMock())
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: result => console.log("switchMap", result)
      });

    //Option 2
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, "click")
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        mergeMap($event => this.saveMock())
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: result => console.log("debounceTime", result)
      });
  }
  //End solution 2;

  saveMock(): Observable<any> {
    return of({ description: "Hello World!" }).pipe(delay(1000));
  }
}
```

**Resources**

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hjw5x2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[switchMap - learn rjxs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

[debounceTime - learn rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)

[fromEvent - rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent)